# Make Avatar also a hyperlink

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this section line of wordpress template that displays the name of a team member and hyperlinks it. That hyperlink redirects to the actual page of that member.

```
<h4 class="sc_team_item_title"><?php echo (!empty($post_options['link']) ? '<a href="'.esc_url($post_options['link']).'">' : '') . (!empty($post_data['post_id']) ? insurance_ancora_get_post_title($post_data['post_id']) : '') . (!empty($post_options['link']) ? '</a>' : ''); ?></h4>
```

Above that line there is this line that shows a picture of that team member:

```
<div class="sc_team_item_avatar"><?php insurance_ancora_show_layout($post_options['photo']); ?></div>
```

I would like to make that picture also a hyperlink redirecting to the member's profile.
I quite novice on PHP and whatever I tried fails. Could you please give me hand on that?
I guess whatever you need is on the first section of code. If you need the whole php file please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: (hope it works this way for you)

```
<div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location='<?php echo esc_url($post_options['link']); ?>';" class="sc_team_item_avatar"><?php insurance_ancora_show_layout($post_options['photo']); ?></div>
```

Or check if the var is not empty maybe better

```
<div style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location='<?php if(!empty($post_options['link'])){ echo esc_url($post_options['link']);} ?>';" class="sc_team_item_avatar"><?php insurance_ancora_show_layout($post_options['photo']); ?></div>
```

Comment: It does not. Heres is the output when I inspect :<div class="sc_team_item_avatar"><img class="wp-post-image" width="540" height="566" alt="John" src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/John.png"><a href="https://example.com/team/john/"></a></div>

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Still not though: <img class="wp-post-image" width="540" height="566" alt="John" src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/john.png">
<a style="display:block" href="https://example.com/team/john/"></a>

Comment: I think maybe with another trick , will update in a moment, Tried with a window.location  onclick, does that work out?

Comment: Now its an href but it does not pointing to the members page. Just reloading the current page.

Comment: echo $post_options['link']  edited, plz check :) I forgot echo

Comment: You are amazing RustyJim! For sure not rusty at all!

Comment: For your info it is a bit hacky, not "correct" HTML, but it works!

Comment: Does it make it vulnerable somehow?

Comment: esc_url makes it safer i think, the only thing with this is that if the link variable ( $post_options['link'] ) does not exist, it becomes an error. I will make a fix!